# On Select radio button value insert value into input type

Tags: javascript, jquery

here pls see my js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fuNd7/5/
here when i select a value from radio button it insert into input type value like when i select Neem ka thana the value of it set in 
here is my jquery code for this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#cityshow").click(function () {
            $("#citybox").toggle();
        });
        $('#citybox input[type=radio]').click(function () {
            var buttonValue = $(this).val();
            $("#citybox").toggle();
            $('#cityshow').html(buttonValue);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly you want to do?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Please format your code correctly so everyone can read it without having to invent where the newlines are. Then, describe your problem,  correctly.

Comment: @Karna  i want insert the value of selected radio button insert into <input id="cityid" type="hidden" name="cityid" value="Insert Value Here" >

Comment: @manwal Value not inserted into <input id="cityid" type="hidden" name="cityid" value="Value of select radio button here" >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $('#cityid').val($('input[type="radio"]:checked').val());
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fuNd7/9/)**

Answer (score 1):

Just simple as boiling a egg. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#cityshow").click(function(){
    $("#citybox").toggle();
  });

    $('#citybox input[type=radio]').click(function(){
        alert("sdfdsf");
        var buttonValue = $(this).val();
        $("#citybox").toggle();
        $('#cityshow').html(buttonValue);
        $('#cityid').val(buttonValue);
    });
});
```

I have added input of `cityid` in your html fiddle code:

```
<input id="cityid" type="text" name="cityid" value="Value of select radio button here" >
```

I have set its type text for testing. You have set its `type='hidden'`

[<kbd>Updated Fiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/fuNd7/8/)